# Enhance the scrolling performance of UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, performance, uiwebview

I made a document viewer using `UIWebView`. The load time is short, because files are local, but the scrolling speed makes me so crazy. The scrolling performance is very poor!

I made it using this: code.

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL 
                                         cachePolocy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData 
                                     timeoutInterval:60.0];

[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

How can I enhance the performance of `UIWebView`?

Comment: How big is your file, and what format is it in? For example, is the entire content in that one file, or does the file include links that are pulling in images etc. from other files?

Comment: Are you testing this in the simulator or on the device? At least on my machine, scroll performance is *always* bad in the simulator but is usually just fine on the device.

Comment: Thank you for replying my question. I tested it on my device and PC too. on PC, there was a bit slow. but on Device, so very slow! I opened 3.7MB file of pdf. Actually It has some big images. So, I tested other documents. Some documents were not slow, but the other were slow. I think, Yes, It maybe cause of big images... Thank you for your answer, David and kubi. ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Run your app under Instruments and look for where your performance bottlenecks are. The most likely cause of poor scrolling is that your CPU is maxed out, possibly by some other activity your program is performing.

Alternately, it could have trouble due to complex Javascript in the HTML or illegal HTML. Load your HTML and Javascript into Safari on the Mac and use the Developer's Web Inspector to profile it. Look in the Advanced Preferences for the option to turn on the "Develop" menu.

Comment: Hm, I didn't use HTML for opening a document. Actually, I don't know how to open a document via HTML. Thank you very much Rob, but I think I'm beginner to understand your answer perfectly ^_^;;